# Short story from Aliens’ perspective that ‘cure human racism’ (cheeky)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Ok, so the details are vague but the ending gives a strong hint.

What I remember is that humans are suffering and either:

A) Send out humans out into space for help from other life to get help and they eventually find help but come back much later in the future to see humans barely alive. And they now have a ‘solution’ to most human problems.

B) Aliens find humans in dire need of help and offer to solve most human problems.

Anyway, at the end as the aliens/future humans are informing the Earth humans of all the marvelous advancements they can offer them, they mention that they: “Can also fix the humans being all white” or something along those lines.

I think it’s meant to be a cheeky commentary on race but I can’t find it for the life of me.

Comment: Your question has been closed, but this is not a censure on you or your question. Rather, for `story-identification`, if an answer is accepted, and there is another accepted answer, we mark them as Duplicates so that they're tied together in the system. If you follow the link, you'll find that we've had a number of people seeking out this story, so you're in good company.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of Arthur C. Clarke's story "[Reunion](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62001)" (1971).

The (very short) story is essentially just a message for aliens who claim to have originally seeded humanity on Earth millions of years ago.  The story ends:

> We have a simple remedy for the offensive yet harmless genetic plague that afflicted so many of the colonists. […]  People of Earth, you can rejoin the society of the universe without shame, without embarrassment.
>
> If any of you are still white, we can cure you.

Comment: Oh man... for weeks I thought to myself, the second I post a question, someone will immediately know it. Amazing. That’s exactly it! Thank you so much!